# entitymanager : min and max are not retained by Query

Tags: java, sql, aggregate-functions, jpql, entitymanager

Context: Netbeans 8.0.1, JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.0, JDK 1.7, eclipseLink 2.5.2

It seems like min and max are not retained by Query:
Here is my jpql statement:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT po.customerId.customerId, MAX(po.shippingCost), 
MIN(po.shippingCost), COUNT(po.orderNum) countligne, 
COUNT(DISTINCT po.productId.productId)\n"   
+"FROM PurchaseOrder po WHERE po.customerId.customerId = :Id
  GROUP BY` po.customerId.customerId");
```

And this is eclipselink logging sql:

```
SELECT t0.CUSTOMER_ID, COUNT(t1.ORDER_NUM), COUNT(DISTINCT(t2.PRODUCT_ID)) 
FROM CUSTOMER t0, PRODUCT  t2, PURCHASE_ORDER t1 WHERE ((t1.CUSTOMER_ID = ?) 
AND ((t0.CUSTOMER_ID = t1.CUSTOMER_ID) AND (t2.PRODUCT_ID = t1.PRODUCT_ID)))
GROUP BY t0.CUSTOMER_ID
```

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like count field alias disturb eclipselink, leading to inaccurate result column list:

```
..., COUNT(po.orderNum) countligne, ...
```

When I suppress 'countline' alias, every thing works perfectly.

The most strange is the lack of any error, even warning, when aggregation fields are not rendered.

Comment: Very interesting, sounds like a bug.